# one repo cloned in two places on git bash

Tags: git, git-merge, git-bash

i mistakenly cloned a repo in two different folders on git bash one is located on the root folder while the other is in a folder I created, now all my recent commits and push doesn't show up on the one on the root folder even though both of them are the same, now i want to merge both together to become one repo and be on the root folder

Comment: Why don't you create a temporary branch?

Comment: One repo cloned into two places equals three repos. Not to worry though: separate repositories can share *commits*. They all have separate *branch names*, but you can easily send the *commits* from one repository to another, just be sure to use a *different branch name* if and as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a remote to reference your second local repository from your first:

```bash
cd /path/to/root/folder
git remote add secondrepo /path/to/subfolder
git fetch secondrepo
git switch main
git merge secondrepo/main
```

This assumes you were committing on branch `main` in both repositories.